# How to make a rest style plugin?

Tags: plugins, ajax, javascript, plugins-url

I created a plugin that is basically a crud to write to the mysql database.
I want to know how to display the data on a wordpress page. I'm reading about url rewrites but it seems rewrites are for regular post and just changing the url. I can't seem to find any tutorials on this.

so when I go `example.com/gallery/1/5` it will take me to the gallery with `id: 1` and show me the `5th image`.

Comment: see [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/207989/4771) for a possible approach.

Answer (score 2):

I got a little piece of code here, but it should/could probably be improved.

- Create new `query_vars`
- Create new rewrite rule
- Redirect to specific template which then handles your parameters

**Create new query vars**

```
function register_gallery_query_vars($vars) {
   $vars[] = 'gallery_id';
   $vars[] = 'image_id';
   return $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'register_gallery_query_vars');
```

**Add rewrite rule**

```
function custom_rewrite_gallery() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^gallery/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?gallery=$matches[1]&image=$matches[2]', 'top');
}
// Change this to run ONLY on plugin activation
// Also have in mind that you need to flush rewrite rules if you change them
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_events');
```

**Redirect to template**

```
function gallery_template_redirection($template)
{
    global $wp_query;
    if(isset($wp_query->query_vars['gallery'])) { return dirname(__FILE__).'/gallery.php'; }
     else return $template;
}
add_filter('template_include', 'gallery_template_redirection', 1, 1);
```

Your `gallery.php` can then use `get_query_var()` to read the values and work on with them.

Comment: Well, if you got something very specific, like showing a gallery, it might come in handy to have another file handle that page. gallery.php should include the code that builds your gallery, so you need to redirect it. That happens with that last function/hook.

Comment: It has to be placed in your theme folder.

Comment: Because you will need to work with the query vars in your gallery.php. But you have to define them in the functions.php and add them to your WP standard query vars.

Comment: You seriously need to start from the beginning with your plugin. Focus on one task and finish it (saw your other questions). Research for yourself and try to understand what happens. You do not seem to have understand anything of what I´ve written, that will cause serious problems when you work on...

Comment: No, I won´t use the chat. This code works, in variations, fine on several sites I´m maintaining. You need to understand what you do, not just copy code. Sorry.

Comment: Being impolite does not help. But whatever, you´re welcome.

Comment: @JoeSantosGarcia please note that people answer to the best of what their ability **and time** allow. If the answer to your question just spawns _new_ questions then you could always _ask_ new specific questions or update your original question with your progress.